# Wise men never initiates any action?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

For karma, action is needed, and if one doesn't initiate it, there would be no change, if there isn't any change, there must be no significance of time.

[Source](//www.quora.com/What-does-this-quote-from-Bhagavad-Gita-mean-The-wise-man-never-initiates-any-action)

I have no idea that what context this implies to?

Comment: Which shloka is this?

Comment: If there is no action whatsover ,anywhere ,SRISHTi will be in danger.And that is not something thats in God's plan of action.

Answer (score 4):

First this 'quote' is not from the Gita. It appears to be a misquote or misunderstanding of some verses in Chapters 2, 3, and 4 of the Gita. In fact, it entirely misrepresents the Gita. Some of the verses that would contradict this are (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> 2.47 To work alone, you are entitled, never to its fruit. Neither let your motive be the fruit of action, nor let your attachment be to non-action.
>
> 2.48 Being established in yoga, O Dhananjaya, perform your actions, casting off attachment and remaining even-minded both in success and failure. This evenness is called yoga.
>
> 2.51 The wise, of even mind, renounce the fruit of action. Freed from the fetters of birth, they attain the state that is beyond all evil.
>
> 3.4 Not by merely abstaining from action does a man reach the state of actionlessness, nor by mere renunciation does he arrive at perfection.
>
> 3.5 Verily, no one can remain even for an instant without doing work. For, driven by the gunas born of Prakriti, everyone is made to act, in spite of himself.
>
> 3.8 Do your allotted action; for action is superior to inaction. And even the bare maintenance of your body will not be possible if you remain inactive.
>
> 3.9 The world becomes bound by action unless it be done for the sake of Sacrifice (Supreme Lord). Therefore, O son of Kunti, give up attachment and do your work for the sake of the Lord.
>
> 3.19 Therefore always do without attachment the work you have to do; for a man who does his work without attachment attains the Supreme.
>
> 3.22 ...Yet I (Sri Krishna, The Supreme Person) continue to work.
>
> 3.33 Even the man of knowledge acts in accordance with his own nature. All beings follow their nature; what can restraint do?
>
> 4.19 He whose undertakings are all free from desires and self-will, and whose works are consumed in the fire of Knowledge--he, by the wise, is called a sage.
>
> 4.41 Works do not bind the man, O Dhanajaya,  who relinquishes action through yoga, whose doubts are destroyed by Knowledge, and who is self-possessed.

As you can see the quote you gave does not any any way resemble any of the verses nor does it resemble any of the meaning to those verses imparted by Sri Krishna.

To sum up. Do your action, even the wise cannot refrain from action, so do it unattached to the results and offer the fruits of the action to the Lord. Thus will you obtain Liberation.